# Prove Lagrange's equations of the 1st kind

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, constrained-dynamics

Without involving Euler-Lagrangian equations. I wanted to prove the Lagrangian equation of the first kind. Basically, D'Alembert's principle says

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (F^{a_i} - ma_{x_i})\cdot dx = 0,$$

where $F^{a_i}$ = Force applied in $x_i$ direction.

and $\phi(x1,x2,....,xn)=0$ is the contraint equation.

Hence, the Lagrange equation of the first kind
here is:

$F^{a_i}-ma_{x_i}+\lambda\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial xi}=0$

I need help with the intuitive and mathematical understanding of how adding the 3rd term makes the whole equation zero without needing it to get dotted and summed.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and not HTML for math. You can take a look at how much simpler and more beautiful your first equation is after converting it. You can do the others.

Comment: @G.Smith I didn't know about it, I am new. Thank you for informing  :D.